# Django Model Design. Want users to have "Collections" of other model instances

Tags: python, django, database-design, data-structures, django-models

I'm having a little trouble trying to wrap my head around how I'd represent this data structure using django models. In the application I'm working on users can upload tracks. I use a Track model for that. We want users to have a collection of tracks associated with their account (tracks they have favorited for example). The collection is just references to the id for the track model. Does anyone have any advice on how to go about designing such a data structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give each track a

```
owner = ForeignKey(User)
```

or maybe

```
class User:
    ...
    tracks = ManyToManyField(Track)
```

if you can have more than one user have the same track ...

Comment: I think I may have been unclear. Users upload tracks and in the track model there is a reference via foreign key to the user who uploaded the track. I'm wondering about how to represent tracks in a users "collection" these tracks consists of tracks uploaded by them and other users. Think of it like your favorited videos on youtube. They are not necessarily owned by you but they are in your favorite videos collection